# GeoServer tiles showing different shift depending on the side of the anti-meridian

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, antimeridian

I have two points, one is on the left side of the anti-meridian and the other is on the right side of the anti-meridian.

Both are being retrieved from GeoServer as WFS (red) and as vector tile (orange).

When loaded, the tiles (orange) show a tiny shift in relation to their correct position (red). On the left side of the anti-meridian, the shift occurs to the right, and on the right side of the anti-meridian, the shift occurs to the left.

Note that when requesting the tile as .geojson format (instead of .pbf) I can see that the coordinate of the point in the tile response is the same as the one coming in the WFS response. For some reason, the tile is being loaded with a ~2mm shift in a different direction (depending on the side of the anti-meridian the tile sits).

I need the respective red and orange points to match, as they are exactly the same point (same coordinate) just requested through different services (WFS and TMS).

What could be causing this deviation in the position of the tiles?

[image]